# How Galois group act on $H^1(G_L,E)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves, group-cohomology, arithmetic-geometry, galois-cohomology

Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over a field $K$.
Then, how $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(L/K)$ acts on first Galois cohomology group $H^1(G_L,E) $ where $G_L$ denotes absolute Galois group of $L$?

$H^1(G_L,E)\cong WC(E/K)$, where $WC(E/K)$ is a group of torsos of $E/K$. For torsor, $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ acts on its coefficients, that is, the action is given by $C\to C^{\sigma}$.
What is the corresponding action to $H^1(G_L,E)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The functor $-^{G_L}\colon G_L\text{-mod}\to\mathrm{Ab}$ factors through as
$$G_L\text{-mod}\xrightarrow{\bullet^{G_L}} \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)\text{-mod}\xrightarrow{\text{forget}}\mathrm{Ab}.$$
Since the forgetful functor $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)\text{-mod}\to\mathrm{Ab}$ is exact, the derived functors of the composition $\bullet^{G_L}\colon G_L\text{-mod}\to\mathrm{Ab}$, which is exactly the Galois cohomology $H^i(G_K,\bullet)$ is the composition of the $i$-th derived functor of $G_L\text{-mod}\xrightarrow{\bullet^{G_L}} \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)\text{-mod}$ and the forgetful functor. In other words, $H^i(G_K,\bullet)$ has a natural $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$-module structure.

Comment: When $L/K$ is quadratic, is it possible to explicitly write down the action ?

Comment: What in my mind is action denoted by '*' in this question. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461065/tate-shafarevich-group-and-sigma-phic-phi-sigmac-for-all-c-in-oper/461271.

Comment: Wuthrich defines explicit action by conjugate, but I wonder this commutes with natural action on $WC(E/K)\cong H^1(G_K,E)$ acting on coefficient of torsor.